# AngularJS: How to check choose the url inside state.go based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Before throwing my question, I know there have been a lot of topics around this subject but none of them actually has any relation to my issue.

in my angularJS app, I'm usine $stateProvider to switch states. However, my applications requires that I pass query string parameters and I wanted to preserve them.

This is how I did it

```
$rootScope.$state.go('defaultState', {id: 12});
```

and then I do the following

```
$stateProvider.state('defaultState', {
url: /test/?id,
params: { id: {value: ""} },
templateUrl: 'testTemplate.html'
});
```

So now when I switch to my state, I can see the url as follows

```
/test/?id=12
```

which is what I wanted, great !

However, Assuming that there are conditions where I would call `$rootScope.$state.go('defaultState')` without passing the parameter. In that case, I will get a url as follows

```
/test/?id=
```

Which is odd ! I wanted to add the parameter query string only if we detect the parameter!

So I'm trying to do something like this

```
$stateProvider.state('defaultState', {
url: id ? '/test/id?' : '/test/',
params: { id: {value: ""} }, ..
```

so that if empty, we choose the second url and not the first but that doesn't work and I get that id is undefined..

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do without having a second state and a second $state.go() based on condition ?

Can I pass a variable inside $state.go('', {}, .. ) and check on it instead of checking on the parameter for the condition ?

Thanks

Comment: In case of id is `undefined`, why you don't check that? Ex : `url: id!=undefined ? '/test/?'+id : '/test/'`

Comment: @saAction, even if defined, it detects that it's undefined somehow. Plus heads up, if id is empty string, if(id) will return false not true which is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In reference to the, docs for query parameters over [**here**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls),
   your state definition:

   ```
   $stateProvider.state('defaultState', {
   url: /test/?id,
   params: { id: {value: ""} },
   templateUrl: 'testTemplate.html'
   });
   ```

   tries to incorpate the two different techniques for using query parameters in one place.
2. This, however, isn't the actual problem and just removing the params would suffice, just like this:

   ```
   $stateProvider.state('defaultState', {
   url: /test/?id,
   templateUrl: 'testTemplate.html'
   });
   ```
3. What actually happens is that this line over here `params: { id: {value: ""}` initializes `id` to a zero-length string which is also a valid query parameter and so you get to see the `/test/?id=` which is actually what's supposed to happen according to the rules you set.
4. Also, `params: { id: ""}` might be sufficient to achieve the same as `params: { id: {value: ""}`. So if you are using params somewhere else, you might want to refactor it a bit just to be a bit clean.

Comment: By removing the params object and calling state.go without the parameter, the domain= in the url disappeared. That's what I wanted to do :). Thanks for the clarifications!